# When does boosting overfit more than bagging?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

If we consider two conditions:

1. Number of data is huge
2. Number of data is low

For what condition does boosting or bagging overfit more compared to the other one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I read your question as: 'Is boosting more vulnerable to overfitting than bagging?'

Firstly, you need to understand that **bagging decreases variance**, while **boosting decreases bias**.

Also, to be noted that under-fitting means that the model has low variance and high bias and vice versa for overfitting.

So, boosting is more vulnerable to overfitting than bagging.